# Comment displaying full name even after setting another display name?

Tags: comments, author

I've tried everything ...

**Changing the display name of the user:**

[image]

**Changing the author name of the comment:**

[image]

But it doesn't work. The author name of the post is still the user's full name:

[image]

Why is this? How to change the author name of that comment to the display name?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to visit your site as an anonymous user, because the field "display name publicly as" should work in comment sections too.
Try opening a "private navigation" window from your favorite browser and check.